# How to decode modules of any python package? example pygame.base

Tags: encoding, file-io, module, pygame, python-internals

I am student and trying to explore more about python internal. I used python package named '**pygame**' and now trying to know its internal working.

I found this in pygame.**init** file.

```
from pygame.base import *
```

But this module is not  readable
its is named as
**base.cp37-win_amd64.pyd**
[Here is the picture of given file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ozhwi.jpg)

```
with open("base.cp37-win_amd64.pyd ", " r") as a:

print(a.read() )
```

Thia shows me an error and i don't know encoding of given module.
Please help me i am a beginner

Comment: a Python `.pyd` is a type of python dynamic link library - a binary file.  You can find the pygame source code here: https://github.com/pygame

Comment: [Python internals](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+internals&oq=python+internals)?

Answer (score 0):

A Python .pyd is a type of python dynamic link library - a binary file. You can find the pygame source code here: [github.com/pygame](https://github.com/pygame)